# Intercepting Cy.Request Stops Program Flow?

Tags: cypress

I am writing some Cypress tests. For my use case, I need to make an api request and then "intercept" the request.

I believe that's it not really possible to do this with cy.request() and cy.intercept(). However, I thought it could be done with "fetch" and "intercept".

This is what I have so far:

```
const requestBody = 'XXXXX'
apiUrl = 'XXXXX' 
cy.intercept('POST', 'apiUrl', {fixture: 'video.json'})
    .as('user')
    .then(() => {
        fetch('apiUrl' , {method: 'POST', body: requestBody})
          .then((r) => r.json())
          .then((body) => {
          })
      })
    cy.wait('@user').its('response.body')
```

I am hiding the apiUrl & requestBody for security reasons. I have a fixture file named "video.json" that looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
      "currentUser": {
        "id": 99,
        "pending_sessions": [
          {
            "id": "950",
            "patient": {
              "id": "106",
              "call9_location": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "test",
                "abbreviation": "aa"
              },
              "ot_session_id": "123",
              "ot_token": "ABC"
            },
            "most_recent_caller": {
              "id": "9",
              "meta_type": "Technician",
              "first_name": "Test",
              "last_name": "Tester"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

When the Cypress test runs I do see the Cypress api request being made and the response being intercepted with the correct data from the fixture file.

[image]

However, the way the app I am using works is that if this API response has anything in the "pending sessions" node then a popup should appear in the browser. As seen in the image above, the API response does have something in the "pending sessions" node. But, the popup is not appearing.

Is there some weirdness that I am not aware of with Cypress where intercepting a request like I have done above would cause program flow to stop executing? Or does anyone have any idea what I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be concerned about exposing sensitive URLs, there is a sample API `jsonplaceholder` that can be used to give a reproducible example.

---

The basic premise of your test is sound, at least if you issue a `fetch` in the test it can be intercepted with `.intercept()`.

The problem is there are two `window` objects involved

- the `window` of the test runner. If you just use bare `fetch(...)` (as you have done), that is the window that it runs against.
- the `window` of the iframe in which your app is running. If you want to affect the app, the `fetch` should at least be in that window.

This may still not cause the popup to appear, since probably your app uses javascript to do that.

You need to find whatever trigger in the app starts the `fetch` and subsequently invokes the popup afterwards.  Maybe it's a menu or button click.

---

In any case, here is a refactoring of your test that runs the `fetch` from the app window, in case that gives you some help.

```js
it('intercepts a request from the test', () => {
  
  const requestBody = 'XXXXX'
  const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' 
  cy.intercept('POST', apiUrl, {fixture: 'video.json'}).as('user')

  cy.then(() => {
    cy.window().then(win => {
      win.fetch(apiUrl , {method: 'POST', body: requestBody})
    })
  })

  const video = require('../fixtures/video.json')
  
  cy.wait('@user')
    .its('response.body')
    .its('data.currentUser.pending_sessions')
    .should('deep.eq', video.data.currentUser.pending_sessions)
})
```

---

By the way don't mix naming conventions in the same API, for better discoverability -
i.e `currentUser` & `pendingSessions` not `currentUser` & `pending_sessions`.